# Make Prediction from single observation using pySpark Model

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a simple linear regression model and I would like to make a prediction based on an observation. Think of it as a housing prediction model that is based on one feature, area in sq. feet.

I have trained the model and saved the model to disk. I then load the model as follows:

```
sameModel = LinearRegressionModel.load("spark_models/new_asset_lrm_model.model")
```

Next, I would like to make a prediction based on an observation, say, 10,000:

In sklearn we can do:

```
lm.predict([[10000]])
```

How would I do the same in pySpark?

The worst case would be to create a dataframe on this single observation and pass that. This may work, but is this the right way to do it?

Comment: You have two options: 1) Do as you said and create a dataframe with the single observation and pass that. 2) Get the coefficient and intercept of the model and compute the prediction manually. In this case (one coefficient), option 2 is probably your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for a quick comment. There is really no other way than these two, eh? Nothing similar to what we have in sklearn? Interesting...

Comment: spark is intended for big data processing. it's not optimized for single calculations like this. thus in order to do it in spark, you will incur the large overhead of creating a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it to dataframe or rdd depending on type of your module. (spark mllib use rdd and spark ml use df)

```
test_df = spark.createDataFrame([(1000)], 'features')
predicted_df = lm.predict(test_df)
```